# Function not sending alert in browser HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, return, alert

Newbie to HTML and Javascript here.

I am coding up a very basic program that allows a user to enter a card number and the browser should say if it is a valid number (between 13-16 digits) or not.

The website pulls up and shows everything I want it to, but when a number is entered (valid or invalid) the alert is not sent to say if the number was good or not.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Card Reader</title>
  <link type=’text/css’/>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    function getNumber(cardNum) {
        if (cardNum.length > 16 || cardNum.length < 13) {
            alert(‘This is not valid.’);
            return false;}
        else {
            alert(‘This is valid.’);
            return true;}
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload=“document.cardNum()”>

<h4> Enter Credit Card Number: </h4>
<form>
    <input type='text' id=‘cardNum’ name=‘cardNum’/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value=Submit onclick = “getNumber(cardNum)”/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One Suggestion though!.....use HTML5 input validations https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was 3 things i fixed;
1- onload=“document.cardNum()” , there is no function like that so your page crashes immediately so no further script executes
2- I dont know if it is spoilt during paste but some of your quotes are not valid, you should use " and ' 
3- This one just prevents working right; In your function you pass input's reference and check HTML element's length you need to check input's value

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Card Reader</title>
  <link type=’text/css’/>
  <script>
    function getNumber(cardNum) {
        if (cardNum.value.length > 16 || cardNum.value.length < 13) {
            alert("This is not valid.");
            return false;}
        else {
            alert("This is valid.");
            return true;}
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<h4> Enter Credit Card Number: </h4>
<form>
    <input type='text' id="cardNum" name="cardNum"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value=Submit onclick = "getNumber(cardNum)"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Shubham oli suggested you can also make use of HTML5 validations as below.

```
<form >
    <input type='text'  id="cardNum"  name="cardNum" required pattern='[0-9]{13,16}'/ >
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value='Submit' >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Card Reader</title>
    <link type=’text/css’/>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("cardNum").value;
        if (isNaN(x) || x.length < 13 || x.length > 16) {
          alert("Input not valid");
        } else {
          alert("Input OK");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>Enter Credit Card Number:</h4>

    <input type="text" id="cardNum" name="cardNum" />

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a simple and direct approach.

Answer (score -1):

There was 3 things i fixed; 1- onload=“document.cardNum()” , there is no function like that so your page crashes immediately so no further script executes 2- I dont know if it is spoilt during paste but some of your quotes are not valid, you should use " and ' 3- This one just prevents working right; In your function you pass input's reference and check HTML element's length you need to check input's value

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Card Reader</title>
  <link type='text/css'/>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    function getNumber(cardNum) {
        if (cardNum.length <= 16 && cardNum.length >= 13) {
            alert('This is valid.');
            return false;
          }
        else {
            alert('This is not valid.');
            return true;
          }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<h4> Enter Credit Card Number: </h4>
<form>
    <input type='text' id='cardNum' name='cardNum'/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value='Submit' onclick="getNumber(document.getElementById('cardNum').value)"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```